# How to avoid angular.js preemptively fetching data until certain actions

Tags: angularjs

Just started out using angular.js and implemented a directive that reads from a property in the scope that's defined only when a button is clicked. The UI looks fine also because the directive part is only shown when the button is clicked. However in the console when the page is first loaded there is an error message saying "Cannot read property someProperty of undefined".

I must be violating some angular principles but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Note: Didn't do a fiddle because this is a general question.

Comment: No, This may be a common question but the answer is always something to do with the code you have written so you need to provide that somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have code patten like

```
$scope.myObject.property
```

then you could see the error when `myObject` is `undefined`.

One *possible* way to eliminate the error the code work is make sure the object is ***always*** initialized when any property is intended to be referred.

You can put this line before the property is referred.

```
$scope.myObject = {};
```

Or do

```
if($scope.myObject !== undefined){
    ...
}
```

There is no rocket science here.

Comment: Thank you for the note --- I actually did that and as Pinocchio has pointed out I don't think the original issue was quite exactly a declaration issue since parts of the object showed and parts didn't. The error message was from one of my console logs and not from the directive. However I have a hard time putting it on jsfiddle because parts of it talks with the backend $resource via a callback. Any idea on how to present the code better? Thanks!